wifi disconnects and keep on failing after sleep/suspend
I have a ubuntu system 24.04
My wifi works properly on mobile hotspot and few other wifi networks. But when I connect to my workspace wifi and if I put my laptop on sleep and open again. The wifi will try to connect and keep on failing. i tried turning off the power management off but still facing this issue!
